# does php have any concept of config files or a global.asax?

Tags: php

Coming from a .net background so bear with me!

Does php have anything like a web.config or a global.asax file or is it simply dropping the application in the file system and boom it is running on the web server? (obviously dropping the files mapped in apache for the domain etc).

Specifically thinking of setting up wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a parser itself. It is not a framework. In ASP.NET, it is a Framework and thus it has its own config files.

As for PHP, we have php.ini - the PHP configuration that sets how PHP behaves and so on.

However for application level, you can create your own configuration file. Normally if you use a PHP framework, they will have an application level configuration file (eg. "config.php") which will decide how the framework will work and so on.

Wordpress installation is quite simple.

Comment: hey Imran thanks for the fix =)
i haven't noticed it until you edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the files ;-)

Of course, you'll need to have created the database (and db user), set up the Apache's VirtualHost, and you'll have to configure the application itself...

... But there is no notion of "application server" in PHP+Apache.

About wordpress, there should be some file explaining how to install, btw ; but it's not harder than dropping the files, maybe creating the configuration one, and a couple of "next" screens ;-)

Comment: About using Wordpress, don't. Just don't. Unless you'd like your webserver to be rooted by some idiotic eval() exploit.

Comment: Anecdotes are fine, but pointers to data and debates allow a more defensible position. Here's a post criticizing the WordPress platform (or ecosystem) with a rebuttal in the comments (by Matt of WP no less). http://www.movabletype.com/blog/2008/06/movable-type-a-history-of-secu.html Infrastructure security is a complex issue - this is only a starting point.

Comment: Didn't realize security was such an issue, considering how many installs they have, that's scary!